# Matrix norm in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I need to compute the Frobenius norm in order to achieve this formula using the TensorFlow framework:

[image: Formula]

where `w` is a matrix with 50 rows and 100 columns.

I tried to write something, but I don't understand how to fill out the `axis` argument.

```
tf.pow(
    tf.norm(x, ord='fro', axis=?), 2
)
```

According to the [TensorFlow docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/norm) I have to use a 2-tuple (or a 2-list) because it *determines the axies in tensor over which to compute a matrix norm*, but I simply need a plain Frobenius norm. In `SciPy`, for example, I can do it without specify any axis.

So, what should I use as `axis` to emulate the `SciPy` function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So the Frobenius norm is a sum over a `nxm` matrix, but `tf.norm` allows to process several vectors and matrices in batch.

To better understand, imagine you have a rank 3 tensor:

`t = [[[2], [4], [6]], [[8], [10], [12]], [[14], [16], [18]]]`

It can be seen as several matrices aligned over one direction, but the function can't figure by itself which one. It could be either a batch of the following matrices:

`[2, 4, 6] , [8 ,10, 12], [14, 16, 18]`

or

`[2 8 14], [4, 10, 16], [6, 12, 18]`

So basically `axis` tells which directions you want to consider when doing the summation in the Frobenius norm.

In your case, any of `[1,2]` or `[-2,-1]` would do the trick.

Answer (score 4):

Independent of the number of dimensions of the tensor,

```
tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(w)))
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

> Negative indices are supported. Example: If you are passing a tensor that can be either a matrix or a batch of matrices at runtime, pass axis=[-2,-1] instead of axis=None to make sure that matrix norms are computed.

I just tested and [-2,-1] works.

Comment: I read it too, but it wasn't clear to me the reason behind that.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me you are better off simply calling

```
tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(x, x))
```

Calling `norm` which square-roots the above result,  then `pow` which work for any power and therefore potentially uses an elaborate algorithm, is overkill.

Comment: I don't think that 'pow' uses an elaborate algorithm in that case, because probably it is optimized to work easier when the exponent is 2 or 3 (the most used). Anyways I was talking about a Frobenius norm, not just an Euclidean one.

Comment: Hence the "potentially" in my answer. What would you say is the difference between fro & euclidean norm ? According to the docs you link in your post, they are virtualy the same.

Comment: Honestly I don't know what is the difference, but I'm trying to write a formula that contains both Euclidean and Frobenius norms. So, at least from the mathematical side, they are different.

Comment: I like your attitude to dig deep inside the question, maybe I can compare also your method with the canonical one.

Answer (score 0):

Try axis=(0,1). I think, it will solve your problem!!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

Frobenius norm does not work for matrix. You need to create vectors.

1. reshape your array to the `batchsize,-1`.
2. Use `tf.norm(reshaped_data, ord= 'fro', axis = (0, 1))`
3. Using reshape on the tensorflow eager execution may through an error. from `version = 2.5` onwards use

`import tensorflow.python.ops.numpy_ops.np_config as np_config  np_config.enable_numpy_behavior()`

for example of how I am using this :

```
heat_difference = gt_hm - pd_hm
heat_difference = heat_difference.reshape(batch_size, -1)
hm_loss = tf.square(tf.norm(heat_difference, ord='fro', axis=(0, 1)) / batch_size)
```